# Cannot Send ID Product Using Json in ASP.NET Core 6)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm doing invoice product and using cascading dropdowns. Here the view

[image].

When user click on plus button there will be a new product row here example

[image: example].

I using cascading dropdowns to select all the colors of that product. The problems is the size select box doesn't work, as you can see in the pictures its blank. Here my code using javascripts and ajax in the view

```
@model Invoice
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Invoice";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    IEnumerable<ProductItem> lstProduct = ViewBag.ListProduct as IEnumerable<ProductItem>;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                <div class=" col-md-6">
                    <label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold" asp-for="SupplierId">Nhà cung cấp</label>
                    <select  asp-for="SupplierId" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Supplier"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Ngày nhập</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="datetime-local" asp-for="CreateDate" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            @*Phần chi tiết nhập hàng *@
            <table class="tblInvoiceDetail table  table-hover">
                @* tạo 1 tr với nd nhập hàng của 1 sp *@
                <tr class="trAppend table-borderless">
                    <td>
                        <select class="ddlProductItemsId productList" id="productList" asp-items="ViewBag.Product">
                        </select>
                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="" class="ddlColors colorId" id="colorId"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name=""  id="sizeId">
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input name="" class="txtPrice" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="" class="txtQuanity" value="0"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btnDelete btn btn-danger" style="width: 2em; height:2em;" value="-" />
                    </td>
                   
                </tr>
        
                <tr class="trFirstChild" data-id="-1">
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Product</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Color</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Size</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Price</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Quantity</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
               
            </table>
   
           
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-sm btn-success font-weight-bold mr-2" style="width: 3em; height:2em;" id="btnAdd" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary font-weight-bold " id="btnNhapHang" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
      
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .trAppend {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>

        $(document).on('change', '.ddlProductItemsId', function () {
            GetProductByColor($(this));
          
        });
       

        function GetProductByColor(selectedProductDropdown) {
            var productId = $(selectedProductDropdown).val(); 
            var colorDropdown = $(selectedProductDropdown).closest('tr').find('select[id="colorId"]'); 

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProductByColor", "Invoice")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: productId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(colorDropdown).empty(); 
                    $.each(data["$values"], function (index, item) {
                        
                        
                        $(colorDropdown).append('<option value="' + item.productItemsId + '">' + item.color.colorName + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).on('change', '.ddlColors', function () {
            GetProductBySize($(this));
        });
        function GetProductBySize(selectedSizeDropdown) {
            var productItemsId = $(selectedSizeDropdown).val();
            var sizeDropdown = $(selectedSizeDropdown).closest('tr').find('select[id="sizeId"]');

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProductBySize", "Invoice")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: productItemsId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(sizeDropdown).empty(); 
                    $.each(data["$values"], function (index, item) {
                       
                        $(sizeDropdown).append('<option value="' + item.productVarId + '">' + item.sizeId + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<script>
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            var id_last = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").attr("data-id");
            i = parseInt(id_last) + 1;     

            var tdcontent = $(".trAppend").html();
            var trcontent = "<tr class=\"trAppended\" data-id=\"" + i + "\">" + tdcontent + "<\tr>";
            $(".tblInvoiceDetail").append(trcontent);
            loadIDCard();
            var newProductDropdown1 = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").find("#colorId");
            var newProductDropdown = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").find(".ddlProductItemsId");
            GetProductByColor(newProductDropdown);
            GetProductBySize(newProductDropdown1);
         
        });

        $("body").delegate(".btnDelete", "click", function () {
            $(this).closest(".trAppended").remove();
            UpdateID();
        });

        $("#btnConfirm").click(function () {
            if (reviewPrice() == false) {
                return false;
            }

            if (reviewQuanity() == false) {
                return false;
            }

            var totalPrice = 0;
            var totalQuanity = 0;

            $(".tblInvoiceDetail .trAppended").each(function () {


                var Price = parseFloat($(this).find(".txtPrice").val()) || 0;
                var Quanity = parseInt($(this).find(".txtQuanity").val()) || 0;


                totalPrice += Price;
                totalQuanity += Quanity;
            });

            if (totalPrice <= 0 && totalQuanity <= 0) {
                alert("Error input !");
                return false;
            }
        });

        function loadIDCard() {
            $(".trAppended").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

               
                var nameIdProduct = "[" + id + "].ProductItemsId";
                var namePriceImport = "[" + id + "].Price";
                var nameQuanityImport = "[" + id + "].Quanity";

              
                $(this).find(".ddlProductItemsId").attr("name", nameIdProduct);
                $(this).find(".txtPrice").attr("name", namePriceImport);
                $(this).find(".txtQuanity").attr("name", nameQuanityImport);
            })
        };

        function UpdateID() {
            var id_last = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("trFirstChild").attr("data-id");
            i = parseInt(id_last) + 1;

            $(".trAppended").each(function () {
                var id = i = $(this).attr("data-id");

                var nameSize = "[" + id + "].SizeId";
                var nameIdProduct = "[" + id + "].ProductItemsId";
                var namePriceImport = "[" + id + "].Price";
                var nameQuanityImport = "[" + id + "].Quanity";

                $(this).find(".ddlSize").attr("name", nameSize);
                $(this).find(".ddlProductItemsId").attr("name", nameIdProduct);
                $(this).find(".txtPrice").attr("name", namePriceImport);
                $(this).find(".txtQuanity").attr("name", nameQuanityImport);
            });
        }

        function reviewPrice() {
            var bl = true;

            $(".txtPrice").each(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                if (isNaN(value) == true) {
                    alert("Invalid Price!");
                    bl = false;
                    return bl;
                }
            });

            return bl;
        }

  
</script>
}
```

I color dropdown work correctly when I click on the button plus. Its show the list color of product but not the size and when I choose a different color, the Size column works. I want like when I click on plus button both method work correctly.I figure it out that when I click on the plus button there is  no ID is passed to the GetProductBySize method

[image: inspect the website].

But when I change the color it does

[image: change the color].

Does anyone know where is the problem? I really appreciate any instructions. Thank for your reading

Comment: It could be that the first time your `GetProductBySize` request is made after pressing the `+` button, the value for `#colorId` has not been set before you make the call. Consider asserting your `GetProductByColor` request has completed and a color value is present before calling `GetProductBySize`.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: If `Size` has a dependency on `Color`, you could attach an `OnChange` event handler to your `Color` which then makes the `GetProductBySize` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I think you firstly get the colorID  `var newProductDropdown1 = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").find("#colorId");` before you set it by using the  `GetProductByColor(newProductDropdown);` method.

You should get it after you create it inside the `GetProductByColor` method. One way is create another method like below and use it.

```
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var id_last = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").attr("data-id");
        i = parseInt(id_last) + 1;     

        var tdcontent = $(".trAppend").html();
        var trcontent = "<tr class=\"trAppended\" data-id=\"" + i + "\">" + tdcontent + "<\tr>";
        $(".tblInvoiceDetail").append(trcontent);
        loadIDCard();

       GetProductByColorandSize( );
        
     
    });


    function GetProductByColorandSize() {
        var selectedSizeDropdown = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").find(".ddlProductItemsId");
        var productItemsId = $(selectedSizeDropdown).val();
        var sizeDropdown = $(selectedSizeDropdown).closest('tr').find('select[id="sizeId"]');

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetProductBySize", "Invoice")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { id: productItemsId },
            success: function (data) {
                $(sizeDropdown).empty(); 
                $.each(data["$values"], function (index, item) {
                   
                    $(sizeDropdown).append('<option value="' + item.productVarId + '">' + item.sizeId + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
        var newProductDropdown1 = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").find("#colorId");
        GetProductByColor(newProductDropdown1);


    }
```